# If either of two cookies exist do something, in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, cookies

I know that `||` or `&&` need to be used but I can't work out the correct or best way to format this.

My code for one cookie:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) { 
 if($_COOKIE['mycookie']=="value1") { 
 // do some stuff 
   } 
 }
```

But I'd like to include another cookie in this routine where either one can be true for the "stuff" to work.

I'm just not sure how to format this. Is it something like this?

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'] || ['mycookie2')) {
 if($_COOKIE['mycookie']=="value1" || $COOKIE['mycookie2']=="value2") { 
 // do some stuff 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: No you might hit a warning if mycookie exists but isn't value1 while mycookie2 doesn't exist. Try something like, `if ((isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie'] == "value1") || (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie2'] == "value2")) {}`.

Comment: If you try the second block of code, you'll find it results in a syntax error (at least because the square brackets are not matched, and also because on their own square brackets create a new array rather than access an existing one). Often the best way to see if something works is to try it - advice you'll often get here!

Comment: `$COOKIE` missing underscore. Partly why the second is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write all in one if statement if you want like this:

(The OR statement in the isset() function is not going to work)

```
if ( (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie'] == "value1") || (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie2'] == "value2") )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the `||` outside the function, to combine the results of all the calls.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) || isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2'])) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) || isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2'])) {
   if ($_COOKIE['mycookie'] == "value1" || $_COOKIE['mycookie2'] == "value2") { 
     // do some stuff 
   } 
 }
```

Or even:

```
if ((isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) || isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2') && ($_COOKIE['mycookie'] == "value1" || $_COOKIE['mycookie2'] == "value2")) { 
   // do some stuff 
 }
```

to avoid nested `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `if` condition instead of nested `if`. If you required to validate both then

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'], $_COOKIE['mycookie2']) && ($_COOKIE['mycookie'] == "value1" && $_COOKIE['mycookie2']=="value2")) {
    // do some stuff 
}
```

Or if you have to validate one of them then

```
if((isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie']=="value1") || (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie2'] == "value2") ) {
    // do some stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if((isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie']=="value1")
    || 9isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie2'] =="value2" )) { 
 // do some stuff 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It puts all requirements in one `if` statement:

```
if( (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'] && $_COOKIE['mycookie']=="value1") || (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie2']) && $_COOKIE['mycookie2']=="value2") ) { 
    // do some stuff 
}
```